# primeNg calendar Uncaught (in promise): Missing number at position 0

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, date-format, primeng

Dates on my Mongodb are saved in the format:

```
 "toDate": {
    "$date": "2018-01-24T18:30:00.000Z"
},
"fromDate": {
    "$date": "2018-01-11T18:30:00.000Z"
}
```

when am trying to set date to `p-calendar` Like

```
<p-calendar name="toDate"  [(ngModel)]="productId.toDate" class="form-control" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
```

> Error:Uncaught (in promise): Missing number at position 0

**What i tried?**
changing date format Like:

```
 post.fromDate=new Date(post.fromDate).toUTCString();
 post.toDate=new Date(post.toDate).toUTCString();
```

date changes to format `Wed, 24 Jan 2018 18:30:00 GMT`
but Same error persists,
any help will be great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your whitespace, `post.fromDate = post.fromDate.trim();`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue: `Error:Uncaught (in promise): Missing number at position 0`

Check your date `format`:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateValue" dateFormat="dd.mm.yy"></p-calendar>
```

Also i was passing milliseconds as string ('123456'), which is not acceptable and gives `Invalid date`

P.S.
`dateFormat` can be: dd.mm.yy, dd/mm/yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy and etc.